# How to solve such an optimization problem efficiently？

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

Given a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $\mathbf Y$ and a convex set $\mathcal M$ which is a subset of all symmetric positive semi-definite matrices (consider a simple case of $\mathcal M$： a line segment between two symmetric positive semi-definite matrices). The optimization problem is as follows:
\begin{equation}
\min\limits_{\mathbf V} \max\limits_{\mathbf X\in \mathcal M} \frac{tr(\mathbf V^T \mathbf X \mathbf V)}{tr(\mathbf V^T \mathbf Y \mathbf V)}
\end{equation}

I know it is not the best choice to iteratively solve the minmization problem and the maximization problem as it may not converge. Do you have any idea for this problem?

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to ask this question in StackExchange.

Comment: The answer would depend on the convex set $M$ and on how it is represented.

Comment: What are the constraints on $V$?

Comment: suppose $\mathcal M$ is a convex combination of several symmetric positive semi-definite matrices, $\mathbf V$ is a  rectangular matrix without any particular constraint.